# SMS unicode defining whith french accents utf8_decode

Tags: php, unicode

In an sms gateway I want to determinate if an sms should be counted and considered as plain or as unicode
I'm using this code

```
if (strlen($sms) != strlen(utf8_decode($sms))) {
                    if ($msg_type == 'plain' || $msg_type == 'voice' || $msg_type == 'mms') {
                        $msg_type = 'unicode';
                    }
```

It's working fine but it's including also french accents as é à è counting sms containing them as unicode but it shouldn't

Any idea to make an exception for these 3 letters é è à so it doesn't count sms as unicode if it contains them ?

Many thank

Comment: Replace them with `e` and `a`, before you do your "plain" vs. unicode string length comparison ...?

Comment: I can do that but é à and è should pass ok they are not counted as unicode with operators

Comment: I am not saying you should not pass them to the gateway, I am just saying you should replace them in the values that you make your "plain or unicode" decision based on string length on.

Comment: $msg_type = 'plain';

                    if ($unicode == 1) {
                        $msg_type = 'unicode';
                    }
Sorry but I don't understand how to do that :(

Comment: Replace those special characters, in a helper variable: `$smsModified = str_replace(['à', 'é', ' è'], ['a', 'e', 'e'], $sms);` - and then use that variable for your length check, `if (strlen($smsModified) != strlen(utf8_decode($smsModified)))`

Comment: This worked fine for me thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea to make an exception for these 3 letters é è à so it doesn't count sms as unicode if it contains them ?

Replace them with `e` and `a`, before you do your "plain" vs. unicode string length comparison.

```
$smsModified = str_replace(['à', 'é', 'è'], ['a', 'e', 'e'], $sms);
if (strlen($smsModified) != strlen(utf8_decode($smsModified))) { ... }
```